# How to get page title from most actice firefox browser tab by bash or python, from firefox which is in focus?

Tags: python, bash, firefox

How to get page title from most actice tab from firefox which is in focus, by bash or python ?

The follow partly solution, show how to do it if only one Firefox window are opened. ( This partly solution are not able to do this if more than one FF windows are open. This partly solution, check only the most active tab from only one running FF window or if more than one ff window are open, the most active tab, from first started FF window.).

Partly bash solution:

```
var=$(wmctrl -l -p | grep Firefox)
echo "$var"
```

Partly Python solution:

```
import subprocess  
wins = subprocess.run('wmctrl -l', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
title = next(ln for ln in wins.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines() if 'Mozilla Firefox' in ln)
print title
```

Remark:

```
A solution in bash or Python is sought, but not one that requires the installation of a browser addon, based on Javascript, Selenium or Brotab.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) can get the window which has currently focus, which assumes that this is the Firefox instance you want to track:

```
$ active_window_id=$(xdotool getwindowfocus)
$ xdotool getwindowname $active_window_id
```

Or shorter:

```
$ xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname
```

Comment: How to output by echo the output of the two samples ?

Comment: Well you can do `var=$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)` followed by an `echo $var` if you need to have it in a bash variable and echo it.

Comment: On this way I get a "~" as output. Ahh. It can be, "~" are the name of my terminal window and the code dont ask for most active firefox, the code ask for most active of every windows.

Comment: Yes the code gets the window in focus and retrieves the name of that window. As far as I'm aware the OS only distinguishes window in focus and _all_ other windows, so if you have two Firefox instances and both of them are not in focus it's impossible to find which one was _last_ in focus. Or do you simply want to get the titles of both instances at the same time?

Comment: I like to get the page title from most actice firefox browser tab, from firefox instance which is in focus.

Comment: Then the `xdotool` approach will work. Do a `watch -n 2 -c xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname` in your terminal. Then have some windows and Firefox side by side and change tabs and you'll see that `xdotool` will always yield the window name of the active window. I don't have more context from your question where and when you want to execute this. If you execute this in the foreground in the terminal the OS will always have the terminal window as the window currently in focus.